# MEAN Stack - Should I separate servers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, mean-stack, mean

I'm working on a personal project with the MEAN stack and would greatly appreciate advice on which route I should take when setting up the server architecture. Performance and scalibility is important to me since I would like to build enterprise level web apps in the future.

This project will be a image hosting application which will include front-end, private API, and a file storage system.

**Option 1: All on the same server**

**Option 2: Front-end and Private API on same server. File storage on separate server.**

**Option 3: Front-end, Private API and File storage would all be on their own server.**

I'm thinking Option 2 might be the best option, but I would love to learn from those who have experience in building apps with a similar architecture.

Thanks!

Comment: This question isn't answerable as presented.  All these options are equally valid, for different reasons.  It isn't reasonable to expect others to know your working conditions or application usage requirements.

Comment: Hi @Claies thanks for taking the time to reply. I understand it's a bit vague what I'm trying to build is a web app that can handle 100k+ users and 1M uploads per day.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon how much scale you are expecting and how much you want to spend on server infrastructure different cases are suitable. I will try to explain a best of both world.

- For all the services which are API based, they should be on an infrastructure that can scale. For that reason, they are mostly in the form of servers which are always behind load balancers. Scaling takes places based upon traffic type and region. To do this, currently industry favorite is docker based microservices. Another comparable solution is Google App Engine.
- For all the Front-End/UI based stuff, they should be stored on a CDN for optimized delivery. With CDNs you maintain that your application's UI will always be available to end users even if your private API based service is slow. CDNs are cheap and they will have a great impact on your end users.
- For Image/Files storage, you should use a Blob storage based solution. Your server HDDs are mostly SSDs these days and they cost a bunch. Moreover those disks are attached to your servers hence really prone to errors or security issues. Using a blob storage is helpful since it takes care of redundant and scalable storage along with some form of security.

With this model, you will make sure that your files are safe and away from your business logic, your end users can access your webapp even when your core service is slow, and very easily manage server for API/service based scale.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vikram, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You should not bake your server architecture right upfront. But measure along the way and improve upon the desired lacking features.

So I would **go with the same server approach at first**.

But design the **Frontend as a serverless architecture**.

Create a **Private API and a separate File storage API** for reading/writing. These can be microservices ready to scale when needed.

You can host the pieces on other clouds/or use your own to scale vertically/horizontally or geographically.

So you bake the scaling part into your design, but only scale when you need to.

Basically the only thing you need to **take care** now, that your **architecture is decoupled into pieces** so you are ready to scale when the need arises.

*Note*: two good read on the topics are the following: [Infrastructure as Code](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26544394-infrastructure-as-code?from_search=true&search_version=service), [Building microservices](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22512931-building-microservices?ac=1&from_search=true)

Comment: thanks for the reply and resources to help me achieve this!